# Create server at the beginning of pytest test

Tags: python, server, pytest, fixtures

I would like to create server before tests start and then terminate it after all tests run. Description of behaviour below.

First time I run tests:
1. Returns error (below)
2. Tests fail
3. Server is invoked (now server is running)

Second time I run tests:
1. Returns the same error (below)
2. Tests pass
3. Server is shutdown

Error:
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Could not start process server

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def start_server(xprocess):
    port = 8000
    server_path = py.path.local(__file__).dirpath("service.py")
    xprocess.ensure("server", lambda cwd: ("started", [sys.executable, server_path, port]))
    yield
    xprocess.getinfo("server").terminate()
```

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, this is the exact application of [pytest-xprocess](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xprocess) plugin. You could write a simple fixture like the following to start an instance of your server and make it available in your tests:

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest
from xprocess import ProcessStarter

@pytest.fixture
def myserver(xprocess):
    class Starter(ProcessStarter):
        # startup pattern
        pattern = "PATTERN"

        # command to start process
        args = ['command', 'arg1', 'arg2']

    # ensure process is running and return its logfile
    logfile = xprocess.ensure("myserver", Starter)

    conn = # create a connection or url/port info to the server
    yield conn

    # clean up whole process tree afterwards
    xprocess.getinfo("myserver").terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
def server(host, port):
    # definition of your server

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def start_server():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=server, args=(host, port))
    p.start()
    yield
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: This option is not as good as `xprocess` because it does not wait for the server to start

Comment: It **could** wait for the server to start with a couple extra lines of code.